# string to variable in R: error:cannot open file

Tags: r

I've checked a bunch of answers here but i still ran into troubles.

I have dozens of table and matrix to assign so I want to achieve it in a automated fashion. But I got error when I ran this code.

```
a <- paste("wiot_table_",substr(as.character(year),3,4),sep="")
assign(a,read.csv("/Users/Dreamland/Desktop/Replication_JEP/WIOD\ database\ 1995-2011/2009/wiot2009.csv",header=F,
                          colClass=c(rep("character",2),rep("num.with.commas",1641))))
mat <- paste("matrix_",substr(as.character(year),3,4),sep="")
eval(parse(paste(mat,"<-as.matrix(",a,"[1:1400,3:1402])",sep="")))
```

error is

```
In file(filename, "r") :
  cannot open file 'matrix_09<-as.matrix(wiot_table_09[1:1400,3:1402])': No such file or directory
```

I 've check the `paste(mat,"<-as.matrix(",a,"[1:1400,3:1402])",sep="")` and `wiot_table_09` and they both have the value as I've expected, which is

```
"matrix_09<-as.matrix(wiot_table_09[1:1400,3:1402])"
```

and a dataframe respectively.

Due to the complexity of my work, I couldn't use `assign` here anymore. Any ideas here?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are nearly there! Look at `?parse`, first argument is `file=`, where has you don't submit a file but a string you did prepare.
You did to invoke `parse` with the `text` argument:

```
eval(parse(text=paste(mat,"<-as.matrix(",a,"[1:1400,3:1402])",sep="")))
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with the path of the file you're providing to read.csv. Be careful with "/" and "\", as Windows separates directories with "\" whereas Unix uses "/". Perhaps you should try copy-pasting directory's path from the explorer or in command line.

A more readable way would be to change the working directory with `setwd('path')` and make sure you have the right path for it. Then you could simply write `read.csv('wiot2009'`)

Comment: I think It is not where the rub is~